# how to access columns of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

how to access specific columns of a 2D array.The array stores the values from a stored procedure.My code for getting the data from stored procedure is

```
public String[][] getDbTable()
        {

            int i = 0;
            String a[][] = new String[3600][16];



            try
            {
                 con = getConnection();


                 String sql = "exec vcs_gauge @gauge_name=?,@first_rec_time=?,@last_rec_time=?";
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                 System.out.println("date is "+df.format(currentDate));
                 clstmt = con.prepareCall(sql); 
                 clstmt.setString(1,"vs1_bag");


                clstmt.setString(2, "2014-09-01 10:00:00");
                clstmt.setString(3, "2014-09-01 11:00:00");

                  clstmt.execute();
                  rs = clstmt.getResultSet();


                while (rs.next())
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<16; j++)
                    {
                            a[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);

                    }

                    i++;
                }

            }

            catch( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println("\nException in Display Bean in getDbTable(String code):"+e);
            }
            finally
            {

                //closeConnection();
            }
            return a; 
        }
```

after running this code my table is shown which contains all the columns.My problem is how to access some columns of the retrieved table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the datatype of the column you are interested in, you can call different getter methods with column names, e.g.

For String:
`rs.getString("columnLabel");`

For Date:
`rs.getDate("columnLabel");`

Comment: I can access only last value of my column.But i want to access all the values of the column.My code for accessing the values is    while (rs.next())
{
for(int k=1;k<=i;k++)
{
  for(int j=7 ;j<=10;j++)
  a1=rs.getString(7);
  a2=rs.getString(8);
  a3=rs.getString(10);
 }
}

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement further?

Comment: i want to access some of the columns of the stored procedure which generate  16 columns and 3600 rows when i execute the above mentioned code.But when i do as u said then i retrieve only single value of the column specified in rs.getString. how to access the full column not a single value.